# Remove the hash symbol from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, hash

how can I remove the hash symbol in a url?

I have `www.foobar.com/#test`I want now `www.foobar.com/test`.

Is this a stupid idea or have it now bad results?

Cheers

Comment: Its only an id which is set from an anker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method) like this :

```
window.history.pushState(null, "", window.location.href.replace("#", "")) ;
```

This will remove the hash, without reloading the page.

Comment: This makes what I want but it breaks the funktion. Is there a possibility to have the hashfunktion, jumping to the IDs on the page, but without showing the hash symbol in the URL?